# User B can sudo to an user A (not root or group admin)

Tags: sudo

I'm newbie, so please help me :
 In system , only user 'execute_prog'(not in group admin) has permission to execute a program ABC.  Now, I want that user B can sudo as 'execute_prog' to execute this program. How can I do?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just be looking for the `su` command.

```
B@my-pc:~$ su exec_prog
exec_prog@pc:~$
```

Also if you'd like to allow user `A` to `su` as `B` without a password, you can edit `/etc/pam.d/su` and add the following lines

```
# Change 'exec_prog' to the user you want to allow user B to become
auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = execute_prog
# replace 'B' with your username
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = B
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is , we have 10 developers and we dont want them 'su' on 'exec_prog' in the same time

Comment: sounds like you might be able to make life a little easier by creating a group that can do these tasks.

Something like `groupadd devops`, then add all the developers to that group. Once they are in the new group, allow executing the program ABC by the group: `chown exec_prog:devops ABC`